# How to pass a variable value to another server using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

```
#!/bin/ksh

CTN=1
ssh -q user@host 'exec bash -s' << 'ENDSSH'
cd abc/def
./scriptname \$CTN
ENDSSH

exit;
```

However in the remote server, value of variable CTN is not getting passed.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
CTN=1
ssh -q user@host 'exec bash -s' << ENDSSH
cd abc/def
./scriptname "$CTN"
ENDSSH
```

Since you *want* `$CTN` to expanded locally you must not escape the `$` and must not put `ENDSSH` between single quotes.